# Why do i get a RangeError, if i add something to my List?

Tags: flutter, dart, range

im trying to create a new Hero Widget by klicking on my FloatingActionButton. Therefore i have created a HeroCover widget, which holds the single Hero widgets.

```dart
class HeroCover extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget callPage;
  final heroTag;
  final coverImageName;
  final name;

  HeroCover({this.callPage, this.heroTag, this.coverImageName, this.name});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Hero(
        tag: heroTag,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => callPage)),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Image(
                image: new AssetImage(coverImageName),
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
              Text(name),
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On my HeroPage i now Create those HeroCover widgets depending on the following Lists with mapping

```dart
static List<int> matrixID = [0, 1, 2];
  static var heroTag = ['matrix1', 'matrix2', 'matrix3'];
  static var name = ['Matrix Kitchen', 'DAAANCEFLOR', 'Bath'];
  static var matrixIMG = [
    'imgs/matrix1.png',
    'imgs/matrix2.png',
    'imgs/matrix3.png'
  ];
  var matrixCall = [
    ...matrixID.map((id) {

      return MatrixPageOne(
        name: name[id],
        matrixSize: 20,
        heroTag: heroTag[id],
        heroImage: matrixIMG[id],
      );
    }).toList(),
  ];
```

Here i map the matrixID in the BuildMethod to return HeroCover Widgets depending on matrixID's length:

```dart
body: Column(
          children: [
            Wrap(children: [
              ...matrixID.map((id) {
       
                return HeroCover(
                  heroTag: heroTag[id],
                  callPage: matrixCall[id],
                  name: name[id],
                  coverImageName: matrixIMG[id],
                );
              }).toList()
            ] // wrap children
                ),
          ],
        ),
```

Now if i press my FloatingActionButton, i add one Element to each of the lists:

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //startAddMatrix(context);
            setState(() {
              
              matrixID.add(matrixID.length);
              name.add('new Matrix');
              matrixIMG.add('imgs/matrix1.png');
              heroTag.add(DateTime.now().toString()); 
              
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: color_3,
        ),
```

So the .map should find one more element in each list and the next HeroCover Widget should be displayed ( if i add it manually to each list there is no problem), but if i press my FloatingActionButton, this happens:[image: RangeError on Emu screen]

but if i tap on "Home" in my BottomNavigationBar now and back to "Devices" everything is as it should be: [image: matrix added]

i just dont understand why .add is causing an RangeError. If anyone knows whats wrong here, id be very Thankful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your  matrixCall init with ...matrixID.map((id) { , 
so it have 3 values 0..2 
In your floatingActionButton, did not extend matrixCall, matrixCall still only have 3 values 0..2

when use

```
Wrap(children: [
              ...matrixID.map((id) {

                return HeroCover(
                  heroTag: heroTag[id],
                  callPage: matrixCall[id],
                  name: name[id],
                  coverImageName: matrixIMG[id],
                );
              }).toList()
```

matrixID have 4 values 0..3, 
and matrixCall still have 3 values, matrixCall[3] do not have value.

Comment: but shouldn't it automatically add a new Listelement to matrixCall,when the other Lists ( especially MatrixID) get a new element cause of the .map in matrixCall ?